# How do you create a skewed Shannon/Information Entropy?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

The definition of Shannon Entropy for a Random variable with two outcomes is ( From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)):

[image]

Which produces a symmetric graph like this:

[image]

However, I have use case where the uncertainty is treated as importance but I want to skew it so that higher probability has more importance. Basically, what formula can I use to skew the Entropy/Uncertainty either right or left?

Something which will produce a graph like this (similar to Skewed Normal Distribution)?

[image]

Note: I still want the Entropy range to be from 0-1. Can't use a weightage between `p` and `1-p` since that doesn't make it 0-1.

Comment: To me it doesn't make sense why you would want a graph like that, the y-axis is most definitely no longer a valid entropy measure. Remember a binary distribution with, for instance, $p = 0.8$ is exactly the same distribution as $p = 1 - 0.8 = 0.2$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

Consider the curves $C_{a,b}$ with parametric equations:

$$x(t)=t+abt(1-t), \ \  \ y(t)=at(1-t)$$

where $0 \le a,b \le 1$.

[image]

Fig. 1: Curves $C_{a,b}$ plotted for values $a=0.6,0.8, 1$ and $b=0., 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1$. The red curve corresponds to the case $a=1$ and $b=0.8$.

**Explanation**: I have skewed the original curve by applying a "skewing matrix" to the original curve in this way:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&b\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}t\\at(1-t)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}t+at(1-t)\\abt(1-t)\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Hi Jean, the image didn't come properly, so I have edited your answer ;D

Comment: @Buraian Thanks !

Comment: Any comment ?... It is possible to obtain a cartesian representation $y=f(x)$ out of the parametric representation.